# "No Artifacts" in Artifacts column after upgrading to new server with version 2017.2.1

Tags: java, sql-server, maven, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have setup a new server with **Teamcity 2017.2.1** successfully. I have copied the **artifacts** folder over along with config and bin folder. I have successfully setup an agent and it is working great with Octopus Deploy 4.

The problem is that on my project overview page most of my projects have "**no artifacts**" indication. I can see the artifacts on the server(windows 2016) and also when I browse the Data Directory from the GUI but for some reason they are not mapping. I had also notices that I get this error in the server log :

```
jetbrains.buildServer.SERVER - JSP pre-compilation failed: 

http://url/agentsList.jsp?jsp_precompile=true, error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect, will try again
```

Are the issues connected? How do I properly mount the artifacts?

I have already submitted a ticket with their forum but no reply yet.

Any help will be appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After 3 days in I managed to resolve this issue, the problem was created because I kept the restoration file in the Teamcity folder that Temcity automatically restore from. Therefore every time I restarted the Teamcity service my configuration would get wiped out and leave scorched land.

Hope this will help someone in the future. I definitely learned my lesson :)